# ¿Cómo guardar en la base de datos en firebase por usuario logeado? Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase

```
public class Cobranza extends AppCompatActivity{
EditText ET_numero,ET_abono,ET_notas;
Button button;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstancesState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstancesState);
    setContentView(R.layout.cobranza);
    ET_numero =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.ET_numero);
    ET_abono =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.ET_abono);
    ET_notas =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.ET_notas);


    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
}

DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("User_01");




public void GuardarDatos (View view) {
    //int numero = Integer.parseInt(ET_numero.getText().toString());
    String numero =ET_numero.getText().toString();
    //float abono = Float.parseFloat(ET_abono.getText().toString());
    String abono =ET_abono.getText().toString();
    String notas =ET_notas.getText().toString();

    BaseHelper baseHelper = new BaseHelper(this,"DEMODB",null,1);
    SQLiteDatabase db = baseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    if (db!=null){
        ContentValues registronuevo = new ContentValues();
        registronuevo.put("Numero",numero);
        registronuevo.put("Abono",abono);
        registronuevo.put("Notas",notas);
        long i = db.insert("Personas",null,registronuevo);
        if(i>0){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Registro Insertado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }


    }
    //acá modificamos lo que queramos para los chills de la base de datos
    // mDatabase.child("cuenta").setValue(cuentaa); ese se usa para que sea por nombre y no por clave aleatória
    String cuentaa = ET_numero.getText().toString().trim();
    mDatabase.push().setValue(cuentaa);
    String abonoo = ET_abono.getText().toString().trim();
    mDatabase.push().setValue(abonoo);
    String notass = ET_notas.getText().toString().trim();
    mDatabase.push().setValue(notass);


}
```

Hasta este momento te puedes *loguear* en la app y guarda de manera local y manda a *firebase* pero de manera anónima, no por usuario

¿Cómo puedo hacer que mande por usuario logueado y se separe por usuario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En este caso lo que tienes que hacer es usar el id de usuario como parte de la dirección de la referencia de Firebase, en tu caso sería:

```
DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("<id_usuario>");
```

En caso de que estes usando Fireabase Auth para el login puedes usar:

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
```